# Build & deploy individual apps from a monorepo

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, deployment, jenkins, webpack

## My Proposed Monorepo Architecture

[image]

This layout is what I've come up with from reading through tons of articles and being convinced that Nx suits many of our needs where I work. The layout works fine for a company of this size because we need opinionated architecture to keep things running smoothly.

### Goal

I want to achieve **isolated development, testing, and deployment** while using a monorepo.

I have a few concerns with common workflows that I'm not sure how to approach just yet.

### Questions

**Case 1:** I want to work only on homepage, how can I avoid having to have the entire mono repo locally?

- I read about [how Microsoft solved for this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/scaling-git-and-some-back-story/), but we don't have access to Azure DevOps at the moment and I wonder if this isn't solvable in some other way. Also, [the open source tool](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit) they built requires a platform compatible with it, such as Azure DevOps.
- Are Git subtrees a solve for this? Would my monorepo look like a collection of child repos (subtrees) that, in reality, live in their own repos, and are just declared here for build/deploy reasons? This seems to ruin all the benefits of having a mono repo in the first place.

**Case 2**: I want to deploy changes I made to the homepage app without having to build & deploy every app in the monorepo. How?

- Is Jenkins able to use Webpack to solve for this and build & deploy only specified apps or changed apps? Even if all of it is in a single repo?

This may be a simple case of not knowing what to search for, but federated modules and monorepos are also relatively new.